# Error al formatear fecha en Java

Tags: java

Estoy recogiendo de una tabla de base de datos una fecha: `09/02/2021 18:31:02` la columna es de tipo: `DATE`

Al recoger el campo en el java uso:

```
import java.util.Date;
...
private Date fec_val;
...
```

Por desgracia, estoy obteniendo:

```
Tue Feb 09 18:31:02 CET 2021
```

Y finalmente la lógica es:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
boolean fecha = false;
  try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(articulo.getFec_val().toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    fecha = false;
 }
```

Y se va al exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Feb 09 18:31:02 CET 2021"
```

¿ Alguien sabe qué puede ser ?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pon el código en el que recuperas la fecha de BD.

Comment: Se mapea solo, yo no tengo control sobre eso, no uso JPA, ni SpringData

Comment: Prueba con `sdf.format(articulo.getFec_val())`

Comment: Lo que puede ser es que no puedes formatear con **"dd-MM-yyyy"** algo como **Tue Feb 09 18:31:02 CET 2021**. Tendrás que definir el patrón de `SimpleDateFormat` diferente. El primer enlace en Google buscando [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Sal, tiene que ser con String para el parse de Date.

Comment: @SuperG280 ya probé con  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);  y peta...

Comment: No necesitas hacer `parse()` ya tienes `Date`, es al contrario.

Comment: Me es ilegible Tue Feb 09 18:31:02 CET 2021, necesito algún formato en plan dd/MM/yyyy, sigo buscando en google y no encuentro ná..

Comment: "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" con esto a mi me funciona sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución:

```
   LocalDate time = articulo.getFec_val().toInstant() .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .toLocalDate();
```

Con esto me devuelve un formato más manejable dd/mm/yyyy.

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que deberías ver la diferencia entre *parsear* y *formatear para imprimir*, ya que tu problema era al formatear la fecha a la hora de imprimirla, y no *parsearla*.